# Can “que” operate as a direct object pronoun?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

I was reading a [French grammar website](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/des-erreurs-jen-ai-fait-des-erreurs-jen-ai-faites/) and I saw the following piece of information:

> Des bêtises, j’en ai fait ! = J’ai fait des bêtises.
>   Ici, le COD est « en », qui reprend « des bêtises ».
>   Dans ce type de cas, « en », étant complément d’objet direct du verbe, ne peut être enlevé de la phrase.
>
> Mais il arrive que « en » puisse être retiré de la phrase. Il n’est alors pas complément d’objet direct, et le participe passé s’accorde avec son véritable COD :
>
> Il se rappelle son enfance et nous raconte les souvenirs qu’il en a gardés. (COD)
>   **Ici, le COD est « que »**, qui reprend « souvenirs », et non « en », qui représente « de son enfance » (> il nous raconte les souvenirs qu’il a gardés de son enfance).

Unless this is some advanced form of grammar, it has very much confused me as *que* seems to be operating as a relative pronoun here, not as a COD.

Answer (score 2):

A relative pronoun is an inherent part of speech. A direct object complement is a role played in a given sentence. A word can belong to both categories for the same reason a noun can be a subject.

In this sentence, we could say that *les souvenirs* is the COD of *raconte* and that *que* is the COD of *a gardés*, as well as deriving its meaning from *les souvenirs*.

Similarly, *qui* can also be a subject:

> Les sénateurs républicains, qui ont presque tous voté pour confirmer le juge, n'étaient pourtant pas unanimes.